# Convert the value from listboxitem to string

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, contextmenu

I am trying to display listbox item value into msg box .The click event I used it only display the datarowview object not the actual string value.

```
void bt_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  //  MenuItem originalItem = (MenuItem)sender;
   // MessageBox.Show(string.Format("clicked from \"{0}\"", originalItem.Name)); 
    MenuItem clickedMenuItem = sender as MenuItem;
    ContextMenu contextMenu = clickedMenuItem.Parent as ContextMenu;
    DockPanel dockPanel = contextMenu.PlacementTarget as DockPanel;
    ListBoxItem listBoxItem = GetVisualParent<ListBoxItem>(dockPanel);
   MessageBox.Show(listBoxItem);
}
public static T GetVisualParent<T>(object childObject) where T : Visual
{  
    DependencyObject child = childObject as DependencyObject;    
    // iteratively traverse the visual tree  
    while ((child != null) && !(child is T))
    {        child = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);  
    }  
    return child as T;
}
```

Comment: You've asked 9 questions so far, and didn't select any answer. Please accept some answers.

Comment: @user644194 - You accept it by clicking the checkbox outline, not by voting it up.

Comment: you need to press on the tick icon to accept

Answer (score 2):

Try the `ListBoxItem.Content` Property. You have to cast it to a string to give it out in the Messagebox.

Comment: i used it bt it stil gives datarowview